# In the Pyramid web framework, how do I source sensitive settings into development.ini / production.ini from an external file?

Tags: python, version-control, configuration-files, pyramid

I'd like to keep `development.ini` and `production.ini` under version control, but for security reason would not want the `sqlalchemy.url` connection string to be stored, as this would contain the username and password used for the database connection.

What's the canonical way, in Pyramid, of sourcing this setting from an additional external file?

**Edit**
In addition to solution using the environment variable, I came up with this solution after asking around on #pyramid:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
""" This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
"""
# Read db password from config file outside of version control
secret_cfg = ConfigParser()
secret_cfg.read(settings['secrets'])
dbpass = secret_cfg.get("secrets", "dbpass")
settings['sqlalchemy.url'] = settings['connstr'] % (dbpass,)
```

Comment: John Resig has written a wonderful blog post on this exact thing here Keeping Passwords in Source Control http://ejohn.org/blog/keeping-passwords-in-source-control/

Comment: @Madawar, that's a really great post on how to pull that off.

Comment: How did you specify the location of your additional .ini file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I looked into this a lot and played with a lot of different approaches. However, Pyramid is so flexible, and the `.ini` config parser is so minimal in what it does for you, that there doesn't seem to be a de facto answer.

In my scenario, I tried having a `production.example.ini` in version control at first that got copied on the production server with the details filled in, but this got hairy, as updates to the example didn't get translated to the copy, and so the copy had to be re-created any time a change was made. Also, I started using Heroku, so files not in version control never made it into the deployment.

Then, there's the encrypted config approach. Which, I don't like the paradigm. Imagine a sysadmin being responsible for maintaining the production environment, but he or she is unable to change the location of a database or environment-specific setting without running it back through version control. It's really nice to have the separation between environment and code as much as possible so those changes can be made on the fly without version control revisions.

My ultimate solution was to have some values that looked like this:

```
[app:main]

sqlalchemy.url = ${SQLALCHEMY_URL}
```

Then, on the production server, I would set the environment variable `SQLALCHEMY_URL` to point to the database. This even allowed me to use the same configuration file for staging and production, which is nice.

In my Pyramid init, I just expanded the environment variable value using [`os.path.expandvars`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars):

```
sqlalchemy_url = os.path.expandvars(settings.get('sqlalchemy.url'))
engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_url)
```

And, if you want to get fancy with it and automatically replace all the environment variables in your settings dictionary, I made this little helper method for my projects:

```
def expandvars_dict(settings):
    """Expands all environment variables in a settings dictionary."""
    return dict((key, os.path.expandvars(value)) for
                key, value in settings.iteritems())
```

Use it like this in your `main` app entry point:

```
settings = expandvars_dict(settings)
```

Comment: This would be a nice trick for anyone using heroku as well since it passes your deployment settings through the environ. Most people seem to just ignore the ini in that environment, but this is much more self-documenting.

Comment: works like a charm! One thing is that in python3 there is no iteritems() and you should use settings.items() instead.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the separate ini files in Pyramid is that you do not have to version control all of them and that they can contain different settings for different scenarios (development/production/testing). Your production.ini almost always should not be in the same VCS as your source code.

Comment: Yes, but it'd be nice for individual developers to be able to share ``development.ini``, only overriding the database URL setting.

Comment: So write a simple script that dumps out an ini based on prompting the user for some information. Pyramid has lots of templating support built in. Knobs on knobs is just hard to follow.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel, the one drawback I think that comes with the template script-generated approach is this: If one developer adds a configuration setting, even if it's not environment-specific, but it needs to make it into every other developer's config so new code won't break, then each developer will have to re-run the script generation and re-enter all their database and environment details. And, they have to notice that the config was changed or be told to re-generate. Only a small inconvenience, but it seems like it would be easy to get a lot of config mismatch.

Comment: This problem sounds entirely solvable.. ini files are trivial to parse in Python. Your ini files are going to change one way or another, and you'll need a process to update them. If you expand that out to include environment vars as well now you have yet another spot to update.

Comment: I think of settings in 3 categories. [1] Settings for libraries that are the same in every environment (which could arguably just be hard-coded in the actual code), [2] Settings that are specific to an environment, but won't be changed (debug settings, etc.), and [3] Flexible environment settings -- ones that should be able to be changed easily without version control revisions (databases, api keys). That's my approach. I solidify [1] and [2] in ini files, but [3] I leave to env variables. I think it's reasonable to have two distinct spots to update, one in scm, and one in the environment.

Comment: Another approach with the same paradigm is @hircus's edit, except he keeps the flexible environment settings in a separate ini file in addition to the versioned one. Still two places, to serve the two different purposes. The only reason I include mine in the same file as env variables is because I like the self-documentation. You can open the file and know what the environment variables all represent and which ones need to be set.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way for loading secrets from a extra configuration and from the env.

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from paste.deploy import appconfig
from os import path

__all__ = [ "main" ]


def _load_secrets(global_config, settings):
    """ Helper to load secrets from a secrets config and
        from env (in that order).
    """
    if "drawstack.secrets" in settings:
        secrets_config = appconfig('config:' + settings["drawstack.secrets"],
                                    relative_to=path.dirname(global_config['__file__']))

        for k, v in secrets_config.items():
            if k == "here" or k == "__file__":
                continue
            settings[k] = v

    if "ENV_DB_URL" in global_config:
        settings["sqlalchemy.url"] = global_config["ENV_DB_URL"]


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """

    _load_secrets(global_config, settings)

    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.include('.models')
    config.include('.routes')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

The code above, will load any variables from the value of the config key `drawstack.secrets` and after that it tries to load `DB_URL` from the enviornment.

`drawstack.secrets` can be relative to the original config file OR absolute.