# How can I use a system environment variable inside a pyramid ini file?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid, ini, kotti

I exported a variable called `DBURL='postgresql://string'`and I want to use it in my configuration ini file, e.g::

```
[app:kotti]
sqlalchemy.url = %(DBURL)s
```

That's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `__init__.py`:

```
def expandvars_dict(settings):
    """Expands all environment variables in a settings dictionary."""
    return dict((key, os.path.expandvars(value)) for
                key, value in settings.items())
```

Then when you export an environment variable to your shell, the proper syntax is this:

```
sqlalchemy.url = ${DBURL}
```

Once you have that environment variable set within your `.ini`, then you can use the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values) syntax:

```
sqlalchemy.connection = %(sqlalchemy.url)s%(user:pass and other stuff)s
```

Idea stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446566/2214933

Comment: @b4oshany Sorry, I forgot to include the function that loads settings, so I edited my answer. It's a third option to what Michael Merickel suggested.

Answer (score 1):

PasteDeploy (the ini format pyramid is using here) does not support reading directly from environment variables. A couple common options are:

1) Set that option yourself in your `main`.

```
import os

def main(global_config, **settings):
    settings['sqlalchemy.url'] = os.environ['DBURL']
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    ...
```

2) Define your ini file as a jinja2 template and have a command to render it out to ini format, and just run that as part of your deploy process.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing this.

Comment: yep, sorry to be the bearer of bad news - it'll get fixed when I can find time to work on PasteDeploy but that's not happening lately